# PHP Email the PDF file

Tags: php, email

I am using the following code to write my form data into a PDF file now how can I email that PDF file using a simple PHP code as an attachment?

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
$pdf->Cell(40, 10, $_POST['first_name']);
$pdf->Output();

mail('me@mydomain.com','subject','message')
?>
```

This code is download the PDF but instead I need the file to be emailed as an attachment.

Comment: Take a look at the examples in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for sending attachments.

Comment: I highly recommend using something as SwiftMailer that makes this much, much easier.